# Jquery drag and drop an image but orginal/source image is lost

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Image in image tray should be in the tray even if it is dragged and dropped in either first/second div .But it gets disappeared once i place it in either first/second div. i want the image to be present in tray even if it is dragged . could someone pls help?

```
Firtst input div<div class="div1"  ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>

<br>

second input div<div class="div1"  ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>

Image tray<img id="drag1" src="https://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo3w.png" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" width="336" height="69">
```

Javascript

```
function allowDrop(ev) {
ev.preventDefault();
}

function drag(ev) {
 ev.dataTransfer.setData("text", ev.target.id);
}

function drop(ev) {
  ev.preventDefault();
  var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("text");
  ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
}
```

Please find the my work @ [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/hydroxy/bgwzvoj1/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can clone the element, see https://jsfiddle.net/bgwzvoj1/1/

```
function drop(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
    var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("text");

    ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data).cloneNode());
}
```

[cloneNode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/cloneNode)